# how to make a span width 100% of parent li?

Tags: html, css

how can I make a span width 100% of parent li

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <span>
              <a href="#">One</a>
              <a href="#">Three</a>
              <a href="#">Four</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <span>
              <a href="#">One</a>
              <a href="#">Two</a>
              <a href="#">Three</a>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Responsibility</a>
        <span>
              <a href="#">One</a>
              <a href="#">Two</a>
        </span> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I have my navigation bar like this.
it is showing like : 
[image]

what I want is :
[image]

How can I achieve this? When i tried `width:100%;` for the span its going out the li and making each span a to the width of ul.

Comment: You need to show your CSS

Comment: add span display: block

Comment: Please create [demo](http://www.jsfiddle,net) or post your CSS

Comment: [Link for creating demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Why don't you go with div then?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/dmm3p77u/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, simply changing your span and your anchor tag to `display: block` will fix the immediate problem.

```css
li:hover span, li:hover span a {
  display: block;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: blue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: black;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span, span a {
  display: none;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

span a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

li:hover, span {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <span>
              <a href="#">One</a>
              <a href="#">Three</a>
              <a href="#">Four</a>
        </span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    <span>
              <a href="#">One</a>
              <a href="#">Two</a>
              <a href="#">Three</a>
        </span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Responsibility</a>
    <span>
              <a href="#">One</a>
              <a href="#">Two</a>
        </span> </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is because span is naturally an inline element which does not fill the width of it's parent.  When you change it to `display: block` you're telling it to act like a block element, which does fill the width of it's parent.

Answer (score 3):

Please try below styles

```
li span {display:block; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
li span a{display: inline-block; float:left;}
```

Comment: This is bloated. Compare this attempt to the answer of @RinoRaj which achieves the same behavior.

Comment: since the a tag extends, there is probably a `display:block` for `a`.. Only display:block for span dosen't look enough..

Answer (score 2):

**Please try this:**

```
span{
    display:block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/2b8bzpqr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add display: block to the span, or make it more correct and change it instead of a block element like div. Nesting inline and block elements inside a inline element is a bad practice. You can try like this

```
 <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <div>
          <a href="#">One</a>
          <a href="#">Three</a>
          <a href="#">Four</a>
    </div>
 </li>
```

The CSS

```
 li div a { 
       width: 100%;
       display: block;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       padding: 20px;
 }
```